# indexOf question. How is this code working?

Tags: javascript, html

I have been playing with this tutorial that shows you how to make a custom search filter. It works perfectly. When you type letters into the search bar the listed book items display or disappears depending on whether or not the letters in the search input could be found in the titles. So my question is this when you erase the letters in the search bar completely, how is it possible that all of the books in the list display again? if a string is completely empty and it's being compared with a one-word title that has no spaces at all using the indexOf method, wouldn't that return as -1? nothing in the code tells all the books in the book list to display again and yet it still does, How?

html

```
<header>
            <div id="page-banner">
                <h1 class="title">Bookorama</h1>
          <p>Books for Ninjas</p>
          <form id="search-books">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search books..." />
          </form>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="book-list">
            <h2 class="title">Books to Read</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span class="name">Name of the Wind</span>
                    <span class="delete">delete</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span class="name">Wise</span>
                    <span class="delete">delete</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span class="name">Kafka on the Shore</span>
                    <span class="delete">delete</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span class="name">The Master and the Margarita</span>
                    <span class="delete">delete</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

javascript

```
const list = document.querySelector('#book-list ul');

const searchBar = document.forms['search-books'].querySelector('input');
searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    const term = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    const books = list.querySelectorAll('li');
    books.forEach(function(book){
        const title = book.firstElementChild.textContent;
        if(title.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) != -1){
            book.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            book.style.display = "none";
        }
    })

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `.indexOf()` with the empty string will always match.

In other words, the answer to the question, "Does a zero-length string appear in this non-empty string?" is always "yes".

You can try this in your browser console:

```
"hello world".indexOf("");
```

Thus when the "keyup" event happens that leaves the search input completely empty, every book in the list will match.

Note that I would be strongly inclined to `.trim()` the search string before filtering the list.

Comment: Because the empty string is like a string separator between each characters, right? Like when you do `string.split("")`

Comment: @ThanhTrung it's kind-of a deep philosophical question :)

Comment: so the return would be 0, not -1?

Comment: @Will yes exactly